# React: Why does not passing parameters to handlers work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There's something i've discovered recently but i'm not sure why it does work. I used to do this when making react components:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    input: ''
  }

  onChangeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({input: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <input value={this.state.input} onChange={(event) => this.onChangeHandler(event)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I understand this is creating a new function each time it re-renders. So I remember reading somewhere that this also worked:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
      input: ''
    }

  onChangeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ input: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <input value={this.state.input} onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using the latter now since it doesn't create a new function for each re-render. The thing is, how does that work? How is the event getting to the handler if i'm not passing it as a parameter in the onChange prop in the input tag? I'm just passing the reference.

Sorry if this has been asked, I've had no luck searching for an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Sidenote, this is not a react thing but s JavaScript thing

Answer (score 2):

When you say `<input onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />` all you are doing is defining a function to be called when the `onChange` event is triggered. React will call this function and pass it a `SyntheticEvent` (more on that on the docs page [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)).

So all you need to do have access to the event data is to make sure whatever function you give to the `onChange` attribute accepts an event as its first parameter. Notice that in both your examples, you are doing exactly that.

Comment: Oh I see, so this is something specific to React events? Because I remember seeing something similar using promises, for example:

`async function sequence() {
  const output1 = await a();
  const output2 = await b();
  const output3 = await c();
  return ''sequence is done"
}

sequence().then(console.log)`

How does the console.log knows what to log if i'm not passing any parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: This answer should help you out! [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836380/11240618](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836380/11240618)

Comment: Thanks!! Appreciate it