# npm firstline package do not return first line (string) but a promise object, how to get the first line string?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I am trying to extract the first line of a file using npm firstline (https://www.npmjs.com/package/firstline) package using the following line of code

```
const firstline = require("firstline");
console.log("First line of the file: " + firstline("home/assets/sample.txt");
```

however it returns `First line of the file: [object Promise]` as output.

content of file "home/assets/sample.txt" is as follows

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Therefore, I expect "abc" as output. what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises in javascript need to be `resolved` to get the value out of them:

```js
const firstline = require("firstline");
firstline("home/assets/sample.txt").then(line => {
  console.log("First line of the file: " + line);
});
```

As shown above you can use `.then` or `await` to get the value out.

Example using `await`:

```js
const firstline = require("firstline");

const main = async () => {
  const line = await firstline("home/assets/sample.txt");
  console.log("First line of the file: " + line);
};

main();
```

> note that await need to be in an `async` function to work, otherwhise you will have a javascript syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Since the firstline package returns a promise you cannot just console.log the result.
Instead you can use then or await.

Maybe this can answer your question.

[How does .then(console.log()) and .then(() => console.log()) in a promise chain differ in execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836242/how-does-thenconsole-log-and-then-console-log-in-a-promise-chain)