# Not using Promise returned by fetch()

Tags: javascript, django

Is (3) a correct way of using then()?
I don't need the Promise returned by fetch(), I just want obtain an updated array of emails once fetch() is done.

Are my comments for (1) (2) and (3) correct? I tested them by running another then() (4) after each of them, and they seem right. I just want to be sure.

```
function setArchive(email_id, boolArchive) {
  fetch(`/emails/${email_id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      archived: boolArchive
    })
  })

   ##### (Using just one of these at a time)

  (1) .then(load_mailbox('inbox'))               // doesn't wait for fetch() to resolve, returned Promise accessible by the next then()
  (2) .then((response) => load_mailbox('inbox')) // waits for fetch(), returned Promise NOT accessible by the next then() (4)
  (3) .then(() => load_mailbox('inbox'))         // waits for fetch(), returned Promise NOT accessible by the next then() (4)

   #####

  (4) .then(response => console.log(response)) // (2) and (3) logs 'undefined'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does "*returned Promise accessible by the next then()*" and "*returned Promise NOT accessible by the next then()*" mean?

Comment: This thread answered my question. Thanks all! https://stackoverflow.com/q/50836242/12001706

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think you are saying that you want to do something conditional.

*i.e.* you want to do one of three things when the fetch completes?

I recommend you have a `fetch` that takes optional.

In the demo below we accept a `url` and an `Array` of functions to execute once the fetch is complete. In the way we could pass different functions to the method when we are looking to do different tasks. I mixed up `sync` and `async` just for demonstration.

```js
// Lets have three methods
const postFetchOne = async (json) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
};

const postFetchTwo = (json) => {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json, 3);
};

const doSomethingDifferent = async (json) => {
  console.log(`Received JSON - Length ${JSON.stringify(json).length}`);
};

// Now our actual fetch
const goGetJSON = async (url, funcs) => {
  const todo = Array.isArray(funcs) ? funcs : [funcs];
  
  const json = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  
  // Now run each function
  todo.forEach(f => f(json));
};

const testURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
goGetJSON(testURL,
          [postFetchOne, postFetchTwo]);
          
// lets do something different
goGetJSON(testURL, doSomethingDifferent);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```