# Problem with catching the reject in promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an exercise to make a promise which ends with failure which returns the string "Failure". I have to use then to manipulate the error.

The problem is that my output is just the reason of the `reject` and it doesn't even go to `then` and it doesn't `console.log` my string

My code:

```
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject("failure").then(console.log("ended with failure"))
})
console.log(myPromise)
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: rejections are handled by catch(), not then()

Comment: 1. `.then(console.log("ended with failure"))` should be added to the promise, not to the `reject()` call 2. You should pass *a function* to `.then` - you're currently [just immediately logging something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836242/how-does-thenconsole-log-and-then-console-log-in-a-promise-chain). 3. You still need `.catch()`

Comment: `myPromise.catch(console.log)`

Comment: so this is what I need to do?
`const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject("failure")
}).then(() => console.log("ended with success")).catch(() => console.log("ENDED WITH FAILURE"))`

Comment: the main problem, and something not one of the answers so far tells you, is that passed in `reject` callback in the Promise constructor doesn't return a promise - it returns `undefined` which is not a Promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do that will be.

```
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject("failure");
})
myPromise.catch(() => console.log("Caught an error!"));
```

`resolve` and `reject` are just functions that change the state of a promise, but not promises themself.

UPD: Please have look at this doc https://javascript.info/promise-basics it may help to learn promises.

Answer (score 2):

Promises are handled using `.then()` & `.catch()` method.

These methods are called exactly when the `promise` is either:

- resolved,
- rejected

Remember this:

- Whenever a promise is resolved without any ERROR OR REJECTION, it will go in the .then method.
- If there are error, exception or rejection, it will go in the .catch method.

lets look at an example of a promise being resolved successfully.

```
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve("this will resolve this promise");
});

myPromise
  .then((elem) => console.log("Promise resolved came in .then block"))
  .catch((error) => console.log("promise with error came in .catch block ", error));

// prints 
// this will resolve this promise
// Promise resolved came in .then block
```

example # 2:
Example of rejection:

```
// a rejected promise goes to .catch block
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject("this will reject this promise");
});

myPromise
  .then((elem) => console.log("Promise resolved came in .then block"))
  .catch((error) => console.log("promise with error came in .catch block ", error));

// prints 
// this will reject this promise
// promise with error came in .catch block
```

example # 3:
Example of Error:

```
// incase of error goes to .catch block
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  throw "sample exception";
});

myPromise
  .then((elem) => console.log("Promise resolved came in .then block"))
  .catch((error) => console.log("promise with error came in .catch block ", error));

// prints 
// promise with error came in .catch block
```

Hopefully, by now you understand the purpose of these blocks now. If any questions please let me know.